Why does Visual Studio Code insert parameter names in my code?
I type a line of code like this:
var_dump('Hello world');

and VS Code inserts the function's parameter name ("value") like this:
var_dump(value: 'Hello world');

It starts off a gray color, and if you hover over it, it prompts you to double-click to insert it, at which point it makes it white.

It just started happening out of the blue (automatic update perhaps?). I suspect an Intellisense "Suggestion" but I can't find it. It's unnecessary, clutters my code, and irritating as hell.

That looks like resharper's annotation. Hated resharper for doing it by default(hard to read code qickly and unclear how to disable it). Now vs do that too.  They should have a hotkey to toggle it.

Found out it's called "inlay hints" and can be disabled.
Look here: How can I toggle inlay hints in VS Code?
